# How can I get turn by turn directions using gps coordinates or waypoints programatically in android

Tags: android, gps, maps, directions

I have an android app that basically takes gps coordinates from where a user travels.  I want to be able to take those coordinates and pass them into the navigator so that I can get turn by turn directions for the user.  Is there a way to do this in android?

Comment: TomTom spent thousand person years for that task .... (including other naviagtion realted stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Navit` - Open Source Navigation System (runs on Android).
Or `RouteMe`.
Both are based on `OpensStreetMap`.
But in all cases this is a major project.